# How to align div first left then top in div parent?

Tags: html, css

This might seem dumb, but I can't figure out how to do this using CSS.

I want to align all the inside divs on the left side, and when it goes out to restart from the top.

So in the following example from the `cyan` div (included), divs should display on a second column starting at the top again.

Is this achievable ?

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.element {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="element" style="background-color: red;"></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: orange;"></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: pink;"></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: cyan;"></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: green;"></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: lightgreen;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can achieve what you want using `flexbox` -https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @j08691 Ha, I've heard of it very recently, didn't thought of it. I'm gonna try something.

Comment: You can also use column-count: 2; CSS on your container div but this is not very dynamic. I would also suggest flex box to be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using flexbox

```css
#container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-content:flex-start;
}
.element {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="element" style="background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="element" style="background-color: orange;"></div>
    <div class="element" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
    <div class="element" style="background-color: pink;"></div>
    <div class="element" style="background-color: cyan;"></div>
    <div class="element" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
    <div class="element" style="background-color: green;"></div>
    <div class="element" style="background-color: lightgreen;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious but boring answer would be to use a flexbox.

However, you could also be punk and do it with fancy geometry: Make them float right and rotate everything by 90 degree.

Of course, to have contents oriented correctly, you need to rotate them to the opposite direction.

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.element {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="element" style="background-color: red;"><div class="text">Hello,</div></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: orange;"><div class="text">is</div></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: yellow;"><div class="text">it</div></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: pink;"><div class="text">me</div></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: cyan;"><div class="text">you</div></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: blue;"><div class="text">are</div></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: green;"><div class="text">looking</div></div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: lightgreen;"><div class="text">for?</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not the best answer, although it is funny. ;)